# How does Froyo display a Dialog atop the home screen?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, themes

I upgraded my Nexus One a few days ago with 2.2 (Froyo). This morning when I went to use it I saw a Dialog sitting atop the home/launcher screen notifying me that an update was available and that I could choose to upgrade now or later.

My question is, what API mechanisms is this using to show a Dialog (perhaps an AlertDialog) atop the home screen? Having written an Android app, it was my understanding that Dialogs could only be shown atop an Activity, and that a Service cannot show a Dialog (only a Toast).

Is Google perhaps skinning an Activity to look like a Dialog? Is there a new API method available for showing a Dialog without needing an Activity?

Comment: Just so you know the home screen (called the launcher) is actually just an activity itself. You can build a home screen replacement fairly easily. Take a look at this sample if you're interested http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can theme an activity like the dialog, its been there for a while (i think 1.6, maybe even 1.5)

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

That would produce what I believe you are seeing.