# How to show alert dialog in home screen?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run alarm which make alert dialog run in home screen showing . i.e when the application is closed, and when the event time is reached, the alert dialog shows the title of the event and rings alarm infinitely. If the button in alert dialog is clicked, then the alarm goes off, My code is as follows:

```
void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
    ToDoApplicationActivity ap = new ToDoApplicationActivity();
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ToDoApplicationActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.alarm, "...Calendar Alarm...", System.currentTimeMillis());
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this,"Event : ", ap.title1, pi);

    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    int id = 123456789;
    manager.notify(id, note);


   Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM); 
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0)
    {
               mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
               mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
               try 
               {
                   mMediaPlayer.prepare();
               }
               catch (IllegalStateException e) 
               {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mMediaPlayer.start();

     }
```

After this if i give alert dialog code to stop media player, i know it cant stop playing the alarm. Here, even when the application is closed, i need to show the alert dialog. I m trying this for past 2 days.

I'm Getting Following Exception:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: You can theme activity like a dialog, more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167843/how-does-froyo-display-a-dialog-atop-the-home-screen

Comment: I'm Getting Following Exception:

    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get alarm notification then you can show alert dialog in the activity which has no view by starting the activity. This is what you wanted.?

By showing alert in the activity with no view you will see only alert dialog on the home screen.

Comment: But if we close the application, then the alert dialog cannot be shown, since it works only within application

Comment: when your application is closed then also you can get notification in BroadcastReceiver thru your alarm and from there you can show dialog thru activity.

Comment: But I get following error:
The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmReceiver) is undefined

Comment: ya you are right... Now i am getting force close instead of AlertDialog box

Comment: you are starting activity from the receiver, you need to add flagFLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to your intent before starting the activity.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to be given to which calling class intent?

Comment: like this:Intent launch = new Intent(context, ActivityToLaunch.class);
      launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(launch);

Comment: I have to start Service instead of Activity... So I have give like this.Please correct me if i'm wrong... 
Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startService(i);